# Windows 11 disappeared with my Linux & Windows dual boot

Tags: fedora, boot, security, windows

I had a dual boot with Windows 10 in a SSD NVMe M2 and Fedora 36 in a HDD, that I kept choosing the OS by pressing F12 key. I then enabled TPM 2.0 to update the system to Windows 11. After the update that wen successfully, I notice that my boot options has gone and the only option that had left was Windows Boot Manager.

I really don't know if the boot options was gone after I updated W10 -> W11 or after I enabled Secure Boot (this is a requirement to play FIFA 23 and I did this as soon I updated the system).

Is there a way to restore the boot options without reinstall Linux? It has some softwares and codes that I don't wanna lose.

[image]

My configs:

- Gigabyte Z370 Aorus Gaming 5
- Intel Core i7-8700K
- GeForce GTX 970

Comment: Fedora 36 has its bootloader and kernel signed by a key which most Secure Boot laptops recognize, so I've no idea what's going on. My laptop has secure boot on and both Windows 10 and Fedora 36 coexist peacefully and BIOS shows both options.

Comment: Windows will overwrite the boot sector whenever you upgrade it to a new version: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine In the other thread, GRUB can be easily restored without re-installing Linux. Not sure about your case.

Comment: @qrsngky There's no boot sector for EFI boot (GPT) and Windows 11 doesn't support MBR.

Comment: Apparently Windows can still manage to mess something up when UEFI is used: https://superuser.com/questions/1728211/windows-10-messes-up-the-dual-boot-of-ssd-w-uefi-firmware-failing-to-detect-it
And in this other thread it may "just boot to Windows" unless you change the BIOS settings: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589083/dual-boot-issues-with-uefi

Comment: @qrsngky I will try to restore GRUB as you've pointed out

Comment: This answer shows how to install GRUB into the EFI partition: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/589160/566040

Comment: @qrsngky is there a step-by-step for a RedHat based distro? Fedora doesn't support apt-get

Comment: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?313609-How-to-reinstall-Grub-EFI-in-Fedora-with-Fedora-Workstation-Live-media
I've never used Fedora myself, though. But I've seen a warning like `DO NOT run grub2-install`. I found some other links by Googling "reinstall grub efi fedora" without quotation marks: https://superuser.com/questions/596317/how-would-i-reinstall-the-grub-efi-bootloader-on-fedora-linux (and some other results)

Comment: This answer may be simpler for dual booting with UEFI Windows, but I've never tested it: https://superuser.com/a/642515/1686346